# Windows Mobile - Keeping SQLite Database Connection Open

Tags: sqlite, windows-mobile, compact-framework, database-connection, system.data.sqlite

I am using [ADO.NET Provider](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) on Windows Mobile (C#) to connect to SQLite database.

Will keeping database connection open for application life create any issue? I am thinking to keep it open because,

1. It will not allow user to delete database file (as it's already in use).
2. It will not allow other processes to modify it (as it's already in use).
3. Does not require to open connection each time.

Please let me know if there will be any issue with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to keep reference of the connection object in a static way. You should know that the connection can drop after a while, and you must prepare the code to handle reconnection.

Something like clsDbUtils.getConn() would do the job inside if sees the connection is no longer valid.

Comment: The problem is not how to handle global connection object. I can always do that with property or method that will check for existance of connection and creates it if it does not exist. The problem is, will there be any performance, maintainance etc. problems, if I keep connection open for the life of application?

Comment: I read somewhere that operations on database are not commited when we issue insert/update/delete command. They are commited when we close the connection. That does not seem logical. Just to make sure.